# Multiline vertical align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an image and I want to have multiline with `<br>`. The text needs to be aligned in the middle.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>
                <div>
                    <img class="vertical-align-icon-middle" src="/images/friendjoined_icon.png" />
                </div>

            </a>
            <div class="user-details">
                <div class="username-div"><span class="text-design">My profile</span></div><br/>
                <div class="points-rank">
                    <span class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed </span></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="right-icon"><p>hi</p></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I have no idea what can I do to keep the text in the middle, because the image is responsive, it's resizable. Need some help, thanks.

What I want:

[is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPnbu.png)

Comment: Are you only wanting to align the user details? You've got "hi" in it's own cell which is why I ask, you shouldn't really be using tables for layout as they're meant for tabular data. If you want to just centre the text in user details under the image using the markup you have, you could use `#myTable img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#myTable .user-details {
  text-align: center;
}`

Comment: If you're going to use a table, why don't you just add the user details to the same cell as you've added the "Hi" to then?

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in my comments, you should avoid using tables for layouts, if you want to have an image and text side by side, I'd use two divs so you'd have something like:

```css
.image-block,
.user-details {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block">
    <img class="vertical-align-icon-middle" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="user-details">
  <div class="username-div">
    <span class="text-design">My profile</span>
  </div>
  <div class="points-rank">
    <span class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed </span>
  </div>
</div>
```